# How to correctly pass a callback and a state to the Layout element in React Router Dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

How to correctly pass callbacks and states to the `Layout` so that they can be used elsewhere? When I share this as below, I have errors and a white screen:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSearchF = this.onSearchF.bind(this)
  } 
  state = {
    searchBlock: false,
  };

  onSearchF = (keyword) => {
    const filtered = this.state.data.filter((entry) =>
      Object.values(entry).some(
        (val) => typeof val === "string" && val.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
      )
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="content">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Layout searchBlock={this.state.searchBlock} onSearch={()=>this.onSearchF()}/>}>
            <Route
              index
              element={
                <Home data={this.state.data} num={this.state.data.length} />
              }
            />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Menu;
```

Here I pass the callback to the `Header` that I previously passed to the `Layout`:

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header sblock={this.props.searchBlock} onS = {this.props.onSearch}/>  
    </>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

I want to use the callback here:

```
function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="header">
        <button onClick={()=>console.log(this.props.sblock)}>button</button>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Layout` is a functional component, and you are trying to use `this.props` in it; this is incorrect. Get the `props` as part of arguments instead, like so:

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
const Layout = ({searchBlock,onSearch}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header sblock={searchBlock} onS={onSearch}/>  
      <Outlet/>
    </>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

- The `Layout` component isn't accepting any props.
- The `Layout` component isn't rendering an `Outlet` for nested routes.

## Solution

It seems that `Layout` only exists to render the `Header` component. I'd suggest rendering `Header` directly in the `Main` component.

Example:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    searchBlock: false,
  };

  onSearch = (keyword) => {
    const filtered = this.state.data.filter((entry) =>
      Object.values(entry).some((val) => 
        typeof val === "string"
        && val.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
      )
    );

    ... do something with filtered ...
  };

  render() {
    const { data, searchBlock } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="content">
        <Header sblock={searchBlock} onS={this.onSearch} />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={<Home data={data} num={data.length} />}
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```